# Get current optimisation level inside a program

Tags: c++, g++

Is it possible to get current optimisation level?

I want that to check if correct flags are passed to compiler.

Comment: Probably not :( Code shouldn't make assumptions about the optimization levels applied.

Comment: How about a comparison with a known compile? What kind of files do you have available after the build?

Comment: filesize should be a rough guide....

Comment: or you could deliberately include the compiler flags into the program using the build to #define  them into a macro.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe, nice workaround:)

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you mean to find the flags from a binary, with no chance to check the build system, or is the problem that your build system does not show the compiler flags during the build? If the latter, what build system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really getting an optimisation level, but what I did is:

- Found a program that has different sizes with different compiler options
- Run and checked that size changed.

Thanks to Captain Giraffe

Comment: Smaller size doesn't always imply a higher optimization level.

Comment: Otomo, sure, but If I checked that one specific program has size of x bytes with O2, and y bytes with O3 it's everything I need

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the pre-defined macro, `__OPTIMIZE__`. For example:

```
bool isOptimized()
{
#ifdef __OPTIMIZE__
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}
```

There are lots of other macros that indicate other types of optimization, for example there are many flags that indicate specific instruction set optimizations are enabled, like `__FSGSBASE__`, `__SSE3__`, `__k8`, and `__corei7_avx__`.